# "sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified" error

Tags: linux, ssh, sudo

I am getting "sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified" error while executing command like "sshpass -p password ssh user@remote sudo ls".

Can one help me out... I tried it over few PCs. It is working on one PC but in some PCs above mentioned error is coming. Thanks for the answer

Comment: You can usually fix this with the `-t` option (allocate a pseudo-terminal).

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21659637/how-to-fix-sudo-no-tty-present-and-no-askpass-program-specified-error